# Plotting Series on Matlab

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to plot the following function:

where:
F1 = A*t; over the interval [0, pi]

F2 = A*((2*pi)-t); over the interval [pi, 2pi]

F3 = 0; over the interval [2pi, inf)

I am not sure at all how to go about plotting this in matlab and have searched for over 2 hours and would appreciate any guidance! I tried to use symsum, but was unable to plot!

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB can not plot a curve on a infinite interval!However,if you want to plot a curve on a finite interval,you can try the command "plot".